# How can i fill a shape with different colours for each pixel?

Tags: processing

i'm trying to draw a shape( using rect()) and i want to work on every single pixel within the shape and change the colour of every pixel.
I think i cannot use fill() because it fills the shape with only one colour.
What can i do?
Thanks.

Comment: If you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [pixels array](https://processing.org/reference/pixels.html) and the [`set()`](https://processing.org/reference/set_.html) function related to it.

The pixels array stores the color of each pixel in your sketch :

> Array containing the values for all the pixels in the display window. These values are of the color datatype. This array is the size of the display window. For example, if the image is 100x100 pixels, there will be 10000 values and if the window is 200x300 pixels, there will be 60000 values.

However, you need to call `loadPixels()` before accessing this array or it might result in a `NullPointerException`.

For this particular case, you don't need to access that array but I thought it would be useful to mention that here.

Now, coming to the solution. Once you have loaded the pixels, you can use the `set(x, y, c)` method to set the color value of a pixel. The method takes 3 arguments :

> The x and y parameters specify the pixel to change and the c parameter specifies the color value. The c parameter is interpreted according to the current color mode. (The default color mode is RGB values from 0 to 255.)

So, if you know the top-left coordinates and the dimensions of your `rect` you could use nested `for` loops to iterate over every pixel of your rect and set the color of that pixel using `set(x, y, c)`

A sample sketch would look something like this :

```
int x, y;
int length, breadth;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
  x = 100;
  y = 50;

  length = 80;
  breadth = 60;
}

void draw() {
  background(51);
  rect(x, y, length, breadth);
  loadPixels();

  for (int i=x; i<x+length; i++) {
    for (int j=y; j<y+breadth; j++) {
      set(i, j, color(random(255), random(255), random(255)));
    }
  }
}
```

Note that you can get away without calling `loadPixels()` in this case because you never actually access the elements of the pixels array.

Answer (score 0):

The `rect()` function is an easy way to draw a simple rectangle. What you're describing is not that simple, so you can't use the `rect()` function to do it.

Instead, you could just use a nested `for` loop to iterate over the pixels you want to change, and then call `stroke()` to set the color and then `point()` to draw a point. Do that for every pixel you want to fill in. You might also want to call `noSmooth()` first to avoid drawing semi-opaque points.

More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/).